# How to pass parameter to bitstream filter in ffmpeg with tee option?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, tee, bitstream

I'm actually in a student project. The aim of this project is to develop bitstream filter (bsf) in ffmpeg (no problem for this). I need to access parameter in this bitstream filter from the command line, this actually work fine in simple command line:

```
./ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -bsf my_bsf=1 -an -y output.264
```

But i need to duplicate my output with "tee" option, in this case i cannot make it work.. :

```
./ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -vcodec copy -an -f tee "[bsfs/v=my_bsf1=1]output1.264|[bsfs/v=my_bsf2]output2.264"
```

The output of ffmpeg: Error parsing bitstream filter sequence

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string parser needs `opt=val` syntax, so `[bsfs/v=my_bsf1=optname=1]`